# Duplicate Column Error When Creating PySpark DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to load some data into a Spark DataFrame using a SQL query as shown below,

```
query = """
    (SELECT * FROM persons AS pers
    LEFT JOIN addresses AS addr ON (pers.id = addr.id)) tmp
"""

df = (
    spark.read
        .format("jdbc")
        .option("driver", "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver")
        .option("url", mariadb_url)
        .option("dbtable", query)
        .option("user", mariadb_user)
        .option("password", mariadb_password)
        .load()
)
```

Both of my tables have an `id` column (which is used to perform the join) and as a result, I get the following error,

```
java.sql.SQLException: Duplicate column name 'id'
```

Is there any way around this, rather than having to list out the column names with the aliases in the SQL query?

Comment: You can use `JOIN ... USING` syntax. It is supported by both MySQL and SparkSQL.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-join.html

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. You can add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

While both `persons` and `addresses` tables have column `id`, then after join dataframe contains two `id` columns.

You can instead of `*` in `SELECT` statement set explicit columns, for example use expression like

```
SELECT pers.id, pers.name, pers.bithdt, ... FROM... LEFT JOIN...
```

Or use slightly other syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM persons LEFT JOIN addresses USING(id)...
```

Comment: This is not useful. I have explicitly said that I do not want to list out the column names in the question.

Comment: If explicit fields listing is not desirable you could use join with `USING(id)`